# Room Dao conditions

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I am refactoring an old app and trying to change the queries to room is kind of straight forward for simple queries, but now I need a method to return a string according to the query result and I cannot figure out how to accomplish it?

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM $SHIFT_TABLE  WHERE ($SHIFT_START_DATE BETWEEN :arg0.startDateTime  AND :arg0.endDateTime ) OR  $SHIFT_END_DATE  BETWEEN :arg0.startDateTime  AND :arg0.endDateTime )" +
        " OR (($SHIFT_START_DATE  <= :arg0.startDateTime) AND ($SHIFT_END_DATE  >= :arg0.endDateTime  ))")
fun create(shift: Shift) {
    //there is a shift at that time return shift_overlapping_with_other_shift
    //shift is shorter that 1 minute return shifts_shorter_than_one_minute_are_not_recorded
    //else enter the shift and return shift_was_enterd
}
```

edit: this is what I was end up doing, if someone know a better way I will be happy to know

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $SHIFT_TABLE  WHERE ($SHIFT_START_DATE BETWEEN :arg0.startDateTime  AND :arg0.endDateTime ) OR  $SHIFT_END_DATE  BETWEEN :arg0.startDateTime  AND :arg0.endDateTime )" +
        " OR (($SHIFT_START_DATE  <= :arg0.startDateTime) AND ($SHIFT_END_DATE  >= :arg0.endDateTime  ))")
fun getShiftAtDate(shift: Shift):List<Shift>

@Insert
fun insertShift(shift: Shift)

fun create(shift: Shift):String {
    //shift is shorter that 1 minute return
    if (shift.totalTime == 0) {//shift is shorter that 1 minute
         return MyApp.instance.resources.getString(R.string.shifts_shorter_than_one_minute_are_not_recorded)
    }
    //there is a shift at that time
    if (!getShiftAtDate(shift).isEmpty()){
        return MyApp.instance.resources.getString(R.string.shift_overlapping_with_other_shift)
    }
    //else enter the shift
    insertShift(shift)
    return MyApp.instance.resources.getString(R.string.shift_was_enterd)
}
```

Comment: You really need to read this first https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html.

Comment: chandil, I do know how to use room and I've read this article several times.

Comment: In that case you should have not created function body and should have given return type in create function. Do read it carefully and you will have your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that need to be corrected in order to make it work.

First of all, Room doesn't expect the method to have a body, but just a signature. Room will implement the method for you. I guess the empty body method in Kotlin acts like a default implementation, so it will not be used.

Also, I haven't seen any example with complex parameters like yours, all the examples match a method argument with a parameter in the [@Query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query.html), not a field inside the argument.

So, what you're trying to implement should be (notice that I've fixed an unbalanced parenthesis):

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $SHIFT_TABLE  WHERE " +
           "($SHIFT_START_DATE BETWEEN :startDateTime AND :endDateTime) OR " +
           "($SHIFT_END_DATE BETWEEN :startDateTime AND :endDateTime) OR " +
           "(($SHIFT_START_DATE <= :startDateTime) AND ($SHIFT_END_DATE >= :endDateTime))")
    fun create(startDateTime: String, endDateTime: String): List<ShiftModel>
}
```

Notice that probably the argument types I've used may be wrong (adjust it to the type defined in your `Shift` type.

For additional information see [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html).

Comment: Hi Xavier, 
SHIFT_TABLE is a variable in a different file (const val SHIFT_TABLE = "Shift" ).
And in general I do know how to use room(I've build different app with it).
Maybe the way to go is to use another method.
I was just hoping for a more "elegant" way to do it.

Comment: About SHIFT_TABLE, my fault, I've mixed up Kotlin and Java. About you knowing Room, please take no offence, I've just tried to make the answer as broad as possible, as can be useful to other developers.

Comment: None taken :)  .

Comment: ... and `create(...) : List<Shift>`, right?  But it might be implicit, not sure what Room does with Kotlin